# Cross Platform c++ and Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to compile c++ project for Windows, Mac, Linux in Visual Studio 2017?
If not please give me a best way to compile for cross platforms.

Comment: Clang, and compile often on both OSX and Windows. I've found it a lot easier to develop on OSX (or Linux, if you must) and then correct errors in Visual Studio when they appear. Clang (the default C++ compiler used by xcode) is a lot more standards-compliant than Visual Studio. (But, the VS debugging tools are amazing, so...) I believe there's an official Microsoft solution for using clang or gcc under VS. Google is your friend.

Comment: You could also look at something like Circle CI, (or any other CI solution), and build for each target OS on commit. Either way, you're going to need something to maintain the separate project / solution files - I'd look at CMake. It's not a super-obvious solution, but not difficult once you get into the right rhythm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It is not generally possible to do that with Visual Studio.

In *my* opinion, the best approach is to configure your CI system to spin up virtual machines running those other operating systems and then perform the build natively in the VM using whatever compiler those systems provide (like GCC & Clang). With the help of a build system like SCons or CMake you can abstract away most of the platform specific compiler bits.

A bonus is that building your code (and running your tests) with multiple compilers is a good way to find bugs.

Comment: Nitpicking: Last I checked, running an OSX VM was a license violation. But, that may have changed. ? You could buy a cheap Mac Mini and use that.

Comment: @3Dave true, for OSX buying a cheap mac and adding that to CI rather than a VM is the proper way.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2017 added [support for building and debugging for Linux](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/11/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/), either on a remote machine or using some new built in local *subsystem*.

A fully cross-platform solution for you, porting your existing projects from VS could be as follows:

1. Start by converting your entire solution tree to a CMake project (VS 2017 fully supports loading such a project instead of the MS project format of the .sln and .vcxproj files). You can try a conversion tool like [this one](https://github.com/algorys/cmakeconverter).
2. Now that you have a CMake project you can use the CMake build system directly from any other platform. For example on a *Virtual Machine* running your target OS. There, all you need is configuring your CMake project to build with clang/gcc instead of msvc.
3. If you prefer staying closer to home  for now, in terms of editor/IDE that can be configured to build from the GUI -- kind of like the VS you're used to -- look for a cross-platform editor that supports CMake projects [like VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vector-of-bool.cmake-tools).

Comment: https://github.com/algorys/cmakeconverter is not working for me https://prnt.sc/kldh3v i dont see CMakeList.txt file

Comment: Awesome, well-researched answer. Kudos.